# Finding content optimal width

Tags: html, css

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guard/UtpGm/

The `w` is a wrapper, having both min- and max-width.

The `title` inside it has a long text inside.

As far as I understand the following happens

- the wrapper span/div/whatever (tried both `div` and `span` with both `block` and `inline-block` display mode) first tries to occupy as much width as it can, and calculates the width sufficient to have the title on a single line (for the sample its 483px)
- then the width is compared to the min amd max widths specified, and adjusted - in this case its decreased down to 380px

As a result there's unused space inside of the wrapper.

How can I make it occupy "as few space as possible" for the content to fit (to look the same, but without the unused space), given both the min and max width constraints? In the sample case the proper width is 312px.

**Note:** I can do really anything with the wrapper. It can be positioned absolutely or relatively, it can be child of any other element, any additional wrappers can be added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first solution that comes to my mind that works:

```
$('#w').css({"width": $('#title').width()});
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UtpGm/9/

Of course, one would prefer a pure-CSS approach, so I would love to see other answers.

Comment: JS would be fine as well, but the problem is I really use this trick to get the optimal width, and besides title there are other elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such kind of width calculation in CSS.

The only thing that is close enough in CSS for the moment is to use display:table-cell :
http://jsfiddle.net/UtpGm/13/

When you define table-cell its `width:auto` value is resolved to 
`width:max-content-width`. Here max-content-width is an internal value that equals to intrinsic max width of the content.

For `<p>` element its intrinsic max width will be equal to the width of its text when it is replaced in single line. And if `<p>` has `<br>`s inside - to longest line.

Comment: man, you are cheating with <br> =) it wouldn't work, I can do anything with `w`, but nothing with its content (`title`)

Answer (score 0):

for some reason this worked:

```
#w {
border: 1px solid red;
min-width: 10px;
max-width:380px
width: auto !important;
display: inline-block;
}
#title{ max-width:380px; display: inline-block;}
```

Also bear in mind that some of your sample text ie"longlonglonglong" counts as one word because there are no spaces, so it will automatically jump down to the next line if it can't fit on that line and cause a white-space in the span.

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: > text ie"longlonglonglong" counts as one word because there are no spaces, so it will automatically jump down to the next line if it can't fit on that line and cause a white-space in the span

This is made by intention - in the real world that is the normal behavior (some words are long, you know), and we don't want no-wrap here.

Comment: I'm afraid you got it wrong. With your CSS both w and title have width of 380: http://jsfiddle.net/guard/UtpGm/17/

What I need - w hawing the width of title, equal to 312